# Need advice on SELECT query with multiple rows that should become columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id     data-type       data-answer
-----------------------------------
1      car             honda
1      color           yellow
1      engine          gasoline
2      car             bmw
2      color           black
3      engine          diesel
```

Need advice, how to write SELECT so that it would be in output:

```
id       car        color        engine
-----------------------------------------
1        honda      yellow       gasoline
2        bmw        black        diesel
```

Data in tables are to simplify the example.
Have tried to search over the internet for 2 days. No solution found. Need guidance what to search.

Comment: Please read the entire duplicate link.  If you are still stuck after reading it, then drop a note.

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional aggregation either you can do `PIVOT` :

```
select id, 
       max(case when data-type = 'car' then data_answer end) as car,
       max(case when data-type = 'color' then data_answer end) as color,
       max(case when data-type = 'engine' then data_answer end) as engine
from table t
group by id;
```